# Getting crash on date format

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

I am getting crash on checking the date:

```
func cehckForDate(date: String?) -> Int{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    let fromDt = dateFormatter.date(from: date ?? "")
    let curreentDate = Date()
    let order = Calendar.current.compare(curreentDate , to: fromDt!, toGranularity: .day)
    switch order {
    case .orderedAscending:
        return(2)
    case .orderedDescending:
        return(1)
    case .orderedSame:
        return(0)
    }
    return 0
}
```

My crash on here:

```
let order = Calendar.current.compare(curreentDate , to: fromDt!, toGranularity: .day)
```

I am getting `nil` for `fromDt`

i am getting my date as   `2018-08-16 15:04:17`

Comment: What is the exact value of `date`? And you can't attempt to parse the empty string as a date because it will fail.

Comment: i am getting my date as   2018-08-16 15:04:17

Comment: Change `hh` to `HH`. (12hr vs 24hr). And always set the date formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX` when parsing fixed format date strings.

Comment: @rmaddy i changed. Still my fromDt is getting nill only

Comment: check if date you are passing to function "cehckForDate" is not nil. also if you will get date every time then there is no need to make it optional.

Comment: @david If you are still getting nil then `date` is not really `"2018-08-16 15:04:17"`. Maybe there is some extra whitespace in their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @rmaddy said, the problem is your **date format** and your **input** - they **don't match**. `hh` -> 12 hour format, `HH` -> 24 hour format which is what you need. ( Refer the link at the bottom to check what you need to use for your input )

```
func checkForDate(date: String = "") -> Int{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    guard let validDateFound = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else {
        print("Invalid date received. Please check if the date matches the date format - \(date)")
        return -1 //Proper error code for invalid date
    }
    let order = Calendar.current.compare(Date() , to: validDateFound, toGranularity: .day)
    switch order {
    case .orderedAscending:
        return(2)
    case .orderedDescending:
        return(1)
    case .orderedSame:
        return(0)
    }
}
```

The only case where you won't get a proper date is if the `date` is empty or it doesn't match the date format you have mentioned.

Also **don't force unwrap**. Safely unwrap and handle the error case for invalid date input.

---

You can check this [link](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information on date formats.

Answer (score 0):

@rmaddy is right, Changing`hh` to `HH` is working:

```
func checkForDate(date: String?) -> Int{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let fromDt = dateFormatter.date(from: date ?? "")
    let curreentDate = Date()
    let order = Calendar.current.compare(curreentDate , to: fromDt!, toGranularity: .day)
    switch order {
    case .orderedAscending:
        return(2)
    case .orderedDescending:
        return(1)
    case .orderedSame:
        return(0)
    }
}
```

also remove the last `return 0` as it will never execute.

Comment: I TRIED Still i am getting nill at my `fromDt` my device date and time in general setting as  24-hrs time was OFF. if i make it toggle ON its fine. But if i make that 12-hours time toggle button as OFF then i am getting nill only. How can i find out wether user is turned off or on ..based  on that how can i show that

Comment: @david check my answer it solves that issue and a lot of other issues with your approach as well.

Comment: Adding `locale` wil help in that scenario. @RakeshaShastri has also answered in a proper way.